# How to parameterize a less file using Web Essentials?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, less, web-essentials

I have a big legacy CSS file I want to translate to LESS - not a big deal in itself, but it references a hard-coded domain for images. It was a pain in plain css but we managed to handle this a dirty way during development phases; and I thought I could "parameterize" this url using LESS depending on our configuration (development, integration, production) - something like:

```
#if DEBUG 
    @import 'debug'
#elseif INTEGRATION
    @import 'integration'
#elseif PROD
    @import 'production'
#endif
```

Is what I want to achieve even possible ?

I am using MVC .Net 5 and Web Essentials 2013.

Comment: One option that I can think of is to keep the environment specific settings in a configuration file or something and have versions of that file in each of your environments, with the appropriate settings. 

You can import a .less file, and all the variables in it will be available.
@import "environmentSettings.css";

Now, just declare the variables in this css file.

Comment: @ArunGeorge Yep, but our deployment is automated and I can't ignore a such file in git and keep a specific version for each environment, as all the compilations are made on the same server.

Comment: Don't you have a branch for each environment? If you have, you can keep copies of this file checked in to each branch with values appropriate for that branch. 

If you don't have different branches for each environment, your build process should have a step in it, which does environment specific tasks like selecting appropriate files. It could be a step in the build process which picks one of many available files, or using a properties files etc.

Comment: @ArunGeorge Actually I'm using the git-flow convention; so event if I could have a specific version of this file in each branch, but at every releases - which are based on the develop branch on which every developer commit their work - I'll have to manually change the file; and it would not be possible because I don't have access to the deployment server. I'll try to change the content of the file with a pre-build event in Visual Studio, and see if it's simply doable this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I actually found a solution: using a pre-build event which copy a specific file to a file referenced by the main .less file.

So, in the main.less :

`@import (optional) "_Variables";
...some code...`

In the _Variables.less, which is a kind of filler so the main.less find every variables with default values :
`@myVar = "someDefaultValue";`

In the _VariablesDebug.less :
`@myVar = "debugValue";`

In the _VariablesRelease.less :
`@myVar = "releaseValue";`

And so on, each configuration having its own file named `_Variables{Configuration}.less`, all of them having the correct values for each variables.

Finally, in the pre-build event:

`xcopy "$(ProjectDir)Path\To\Less\Files\_Variables$(ConfigurationName).less" "$(ProjectDir)Path\To\Less\Files\_Variables.less" /Y`

At each compilation, the file _Variables.less is replaced by the file needed by the configuration, and the main.less is compiled with the correct values.